# VPN multiple IP users anonymity

Tags: vpn, identity

During a support conversation with my VPN provider, I asked specifically: "is it impossible to filter out a single VPN user since your IPs are in use by many?". The answer was yes, it is impossible.

I am not convinced though. There must be a way to filter out abusive VPN users in this scenario, even if many are using the same IP. Anyone know of feasible methods for this?

NB: DNS leaking, WebRTC and such is tested and secure.

Comment: I believe it must be possible since it is basically the same situation as when a user stops paying, access is then forbidden. The protocols to implement rejecting the service to a specific user may not be in place at this provider, but the technical means should in fact exist or it would create one time payers turn into life time users

Comment: Thank you. With this these kinds of arguments I will go into a new round of questioning to my provider (when I have a couple of more arguments).

Comment: I will submit it as an answer since it seems to have helped you :)

Comment: "filter out" at what point? The VPN provider knows exactly who is doing what, but your question, as asked, seems to be focused on identifying users once the traffic leaves the VPN servers.

Comment: So you're saying that support lied or was incompetent on the matter? The question is simply: can they pin a real identity to the internet traffic of a VPN client?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this must be possible since its the same situation when a user stops paying for their service, they have to be able to deny the service to those who stop paying.

Maybe they dont have the protocols in place to assert an attacker or an abuser deserves to be denied of their service, but that is a different situation. The technical means must be in place or it would allow one time payers become life time users.